How many coprimes to $n$ are also prime?
Given the interval from 1 to $n$, I want to know how many primes in this in this interval are also coprime to $n$.
We know that the coprimes to n below n are $\phi(n)$ so the number that we want must be below it, because it includes the number one.

This is https://oeis.org/A048865, unless I am mistaken.

David, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read this thread and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed because it is a very bad and low-quality question.

@Angelo But as you see, such questions can nevertheless get answers although this is against the policy of this site.

If $\pi (x)$ be the prime counting function and $\omega (x)$ be the prime omega function (that counts the number of distinct prime factors) then what you want is $\pi (n) - \omega (n)$ - this is simply removing that part of the set of prime numbers from $1$ to $n$ which is not coprime (i.e. divides), leaving us with what is coprime.
I am unaware of any exact formula for $\pi (x)$ and $\omega (x)$ (pretty sure there isn't one yet), but I do remember the asymptotic formulae for these functions. Thus our function is approximately $$f(x) \sim \frac{x}{\ln x} - \frac{\ln x}{\ln \ln x}$$

... and how to calculate $\pi(x)$ and $\omega(x)$?

err....that's the difficult part.

@Dominique $\pi(n)\sim\frac{n}{\ln n}$ while $\sum_{k=1}^n\omega(k)\sim n\ln\ln n$ (more precise expressions exist).

just added the asymptotic thingy, sad that you beat me to it :\

From the above comments it seems like OP wants a closed form answer. There are no known exact and useful closed formula for $\pi(x)$ and $\omega(x)$. So you will not have a formula that gives you the exact answer. However there are good estimated of both of these in terms of $n$ and that is the best you can hope for.
The average order of $\omega(n)$ is $\log\log(n)$ and it can go to as low as 1 if $n$ is a prime. But
$$\pi(n) = \frac{n}{\log n} + O(n/\log^2 n)
$$
and its error is already greater than $\log\log(n)$. So any estimate of $\pi(n) - \omega(n)$ is not going to be any better than that of $\pi(n)$.
